# Control fields of views on different pagination

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I use pager (as 1 2 3.. 9 >>Next >>Last) in **drupal-7.43 views** and displaying only 3 articles on one page with the fields title and body.

**I need to hide body of the articles on 3-6 pages.**

**Note:** It should be done by only using views or views handler but not with css or JS.

Kindly guide me to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more information , what is this version drupal ? D7, D8 ?

Comment: Kindly check the updated question

Comment: pagination is in ajax or by get parameters (in configuration of views) ?

Comment: I used pager in the page settings of views.  I didn't use any ajax.
[Click here](http://prntscr.com/dfyfzj) to check the views

Comment: Hum ok you're not using ajax pagination , so you have the number of the page in url . So you have to hook views render on page number 3 and 6 . check this link https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x